# Move file into dynamically created folder with VB Script

Tags: dynamic, vbscript

I am working on a backup script in VBS that creates a folder and then copies a powerpoint file into the most recently created folder.

Everything works great except MoveFile command at the bottom
Here is what I got so far (the bottom code is most important but just so everyone can understand where I am coming from):

```
sourceDir = "T:\Team"
destinationDir = "T:\Team\Archive\Archive"
const OverwriteExisting = True

intNum = 1

strDirectory = destinationDir & "_" & replace(date,"/",".") & "_" & intNum

'This checks if the folder exists and if not it will create a folder with the date and increment the folder name incase there are multiple updates in a single day.

if not filesys.FolderExists(destinationDir) then
While filesys.FolderExists(destinationDir & "_" & replace(date,"/",".") & "_" & intNum) = True
intNum = intNum + 1
Wend

Set archivefolder = filesys.CreateFolder(destinationDir & "_" & replace(date,"/",".") & "_" & intNum)

Else

Set archivefolder = filesys.CreateFolder(destinationDir)


Set objFolder = fso.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
End if

Dim thisday, thisdayy, thisdayyy


Today_Date()

' This is the problem code

filesys.MoveFile "T:\Arriva\Project_Organigram_" & thisday & "." & thisdayy & "." & thisdayyy & ".pptm", "destinationDir & "\" & Project_Organigram_" & thisday & "." & thisdayy & "." & thisdayyy & ".pptm"


Function Today_Date()

thisday=Right(Day(Date),2)

thisdayy=Right("0" & Month(Date),2)

thisdayyy=Right("0" & Year(Date),2)

End Function
```

This results in a folder being created as "T:\Team\Archive\Archive_03.12.2014_1

**My goal** is to be able to move the file in T:\Team to the dynamically created folder above.

Everything works great until the MoveFile part. The destination is the part throwing a "type mismatch" at the line where I define the strDirectory

I am just learning this type of programming so please let me know if I can provide any further details!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple syntax errors with your quotes that are cancelling each other out.  Change your line to this:

```
filesys.MoveFile "T:\Team\Project_Organigram_" & thisday & "." & thisdayy & "." & thisdayyy & ".pptm", "destinationDir" & "_" & replace(date,"/",".") & "_" & intNum & "\" & "Project_Organigram_" & thisday & "." & thisdayy & "." & thisdayyy & ".pptm"
```

Comment: Your added " in `"destinationDir" & "_"` will result in `destinationDir_`. That surely isn't intended.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! It's now saying the Path cannot be found. I'll keep playing with what you gave me and see if I am overlooking something

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner -- I was just pointing out what was causing the error.  I'm not going to make any assumptions about the OP's intentions beyond fixing the error.

Comment: I actually want the result ofdestinationDir_ so the folder output looks as follows:

Archive_03.12.2014_1
Archive_03.12.2014_2
etc.